# Is there a request–response networking API for Java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I'm looking for a simple java library which would enable to write code in the following fashion:

```
Remote remote = Remote.connect("some_host:1234"); 
Future<String> response = remote.request("hello");
// do something else
String reply = response.get();
```

It should be based on tcp/ip and use plain text messages across the network to be language agnostic, so that non-Java servers are also able to send/receive requests/responses.

(Before telling me to use plain sockets, keep in mind that in that case you need to implement wrappers to delimit payload, care about received messages reordering, thread handling... the example is simple, but it is not that trivial to implement *well*.)

Is there any existing API out there like this?

*PS: ...the simpler, the better!*

Comment: It's odd that you do something before calling `response.get()`.  You could just read the socket later; the received input is buffered in the socket.  But most likely the answer won't even have arrived when you try to get it later.

Comment: It's just a common pattern to handle it in an easier way. That way, you can do multiple asynchronous calls like `Future<String> response1 = remote.request("hello 1"); Future<String> response2 = remote.request("hello 2"); Future<String> response3 = remote.request("hello 3");` and handle them separately at a later stage, perhaps after having done some intermediate data processing. Then a call to `response2.get();` will block or not depending if the response arrived or not. It's very convenient to organize your code that way, to be able to pass 'future responses' as an object and so on.

Comment: OK, makes sense.  I had something similar with two connections and I split the response waiting in two threads, but that would not scale well if you have too many response waitings.  By the way, I know nothing of java.nio, but I think that's what it was made for.

Comment: What would the API look like at the other end? Here, your code is making a request and waiting for a reply; on the server side, the code would have to allow threads to wait for requests and then send replies. Or would you like a symmetric ongoing conversation ping-ponging back and forth?

Comment: Just something simple, service oriented ...like a method `String handleRequest(String msg)` to implement and a `listen(port, requestHandler)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service).

Comment: Looking at: http://my.execpc.com/~gopalan/jms/jms.html it doesn't look like this is really what I need. Moreover, messages sent over the network do not seem to be plain text.

Comment: yeah, that's what it is wrapped/unwrapped into. What about what is actually sent over the network? ...I doubt that it is plain text, it will probably be some sort of serialized object or some specific format, containing the string. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well... theoretically, TCP/IP packets have all the information needed inside. ...and even if some "application level" protocol is needed, I prefer it to be plain text to be interoperable with other software (non-java).

Comment: JMS isn't a protocol, it's an API, so it's not meaningful to talk about it being plain text or not.

Comment: Exactly, and the purpose of TextMessage is to, err, encapsulate text messages.

Comment: Well, JMS uses a specific protocol to communicate... And if it's not easily interfacable with other non-java software, it's problematic

Answer (score 1):

Use plain sockets :-)

Sockets use TCP, and TCP takes care of payloads, multiple packets and ordering. You'll still need to handle the threading, but `java.util.concurrent` has all you need for this. Don't forget to decide of a character encoding for your strings.

Comment: 2 related questions: 1. Based on the OutputStream, how do I delimit the payload of a single message? 2. If i send requests A,B,C then receive responses to B,A,C; how can I assign the responses to the correct requests? (I mean, the outputstream will read B,A,C)

Comment: @arnaud I don't understand Q1.  On Q2 you should include in your reply some information about which request it is answering.

Comment: Q1 ...oh, sorry for the confusion, i meant the InputStream of course. When reading from a socket, you access its data from the InputStream ...however, I don't see how you delimit when a message ends and when a message starts, all you get is a sequence of bytes being the concatenation of all messages.
Q2: ...yeah, that's why I mentioned in the initial post more work is involved since you also have to manage reordering

Comment: 1. Now I see what you mean with payloads. If you send multiple messages on the same connection, then indeed, you have to delimit messages in one way or another. You could simply send the length of each message before the message itself, or use a delimiter that no one could ever use in a message. 2. Just write the server application so that answers are written in the same order as their request, or attribute a unique ID to each request and send this id as part of the response.

Comment: Note that HTTP sends one request per connection (unless keep-alive is used), and has worked very well for years like this.

Comment: yeah, well, because of Q1, Q2 and others, I wondered if some API exists which already does that. Moreover, we introduce redundant information. TCP headers should already contain all the necessary information (payload size, seq number (?), ...). I also cannot afford to establish a new connection for each request, it's for high frequency requests/responses.

Comment: Since you say you are sending Strings, the newline "\n" is the delimiter; you should also call `flush()` on the output stream (look at the api though, sometimes you do have to call, sometimes not).  When are receiving the input String, use `readLine()` which returns the line without the terminating "\n".  See the [Socket tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).

Comment: I did my own protocol for something I'm writing now.  Each message is two lines: "messageType\nactual message\n".  So I have to use two `readLine()` to get my message.  But as I said I'm using different sockets and threads to read each input type; this protocol would get messed up with interfering dialogs on the same socket. By the way, I'm not proud of my protocol and was thinking of asking on stackoverflow if someone had a better idea than sending text (XML is one posibility).

Comment: @JB Nizet: You say "unless keep-alive is used", but the fact is that keep-alive *is* used by practically all clients and servers. It's used precisely *because* the one-request-per-connection model was too slow.

Answer (score 1):

TCP implementations usually give to the applications only a stream-like interface, with no access to the individual packets. (Also, some routers/firewalls might want to repack the data in the TCP streams, which means that they do not necessarily arrive in the same blocks as sent.)
Thus **we really need to use some packaging protocol** on top of TCP (or really *on top of any stream-pair*).

A really simple protocol would be *one line for each request/response*, but this will work only with small data sizes (or you need to somehow escape embedded newlines).

If you want it more structured, you could use something XML-based (like XMPP): each request/response would be a complete XML element (including subelements, if necessary).

Also, if you want to use the *request–response* scheme, you will need to either say *responses have to come in the same order as the requests were ordered* (which disallows or at least complicates parallel processing on the server side for multiple requests on the same connection), or you will have to define request numbers, and the responses then will somehow include the request number they relate to.

As examples, HTTP uses the first approach (from 1.1 - before there was only one request/response pair for each connection), while the X protocol uses the second one.

For HTTP, there are already implementations around (both on client and on server side), and it can be made totally plain text (depending on the data you are sending).

Alternatively, we could build our protocol directly on a packet-based protocol like UDP. But this has the usual reliability problems of UDP, and we also need to use message-numbers (to relate responses to requests) or such - which could mean that we have to re-implement half of TCP again.

So, sorry, no real answer other than *use HTTP*.

Answer (score 0):

With [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org) you're able to develop your own protocol, but it might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any library which gives you a layer quite like this over sockets. The IMAP protocol has a framing layer which is quite like this, but i don't know of any way to use it independently of the rest of IMAP. Such a library would be simple enough to write, and potentially quite useful, so if anyone fancies trying it, i encourage them to do so!

The closest thing i can think of to what you want is [ZeroMQ in request-reply mode](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Ask-and-Ye-Shall-Receive). ZeroMQ is written in C, but there is a [Java binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava). It's a pretty good library - there are bindings for many languages, so it's practically language agnostic, and it does indeed take care of delimiting payload, caring about received messages reordering, and thread handling. I don't think it's plain-text, though.